# mysql_query returns the notice "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get an old PHP script to work but I keep getting this notice:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...

The notice is based on the last line of this code:

```
$result_id_check = mysql_query("select ses_userid from fe_sessions where ses_id = '".$_COOKIE['fe_typo_user']."';");
$row_check = mysql_fetch_object($result_id_check);

if ($row_check->ses_userid) {
```

I also tried using mysql**i**_query and mysql**i**_fetch_object but that won't take any changes.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Did you change the database connection when you tried using `mysqli_`

Comment: This message normally happens in this type of code when the query fails. **Does that error have a line number associated with it**

Comment: Did the query find any results?

Comment: if query return 0 rows while possible this error

Comment: You should check if $row_check is object for example using if (!is_object($row_check)) die('row_check is not an object'); before if ($row_check->ses_userid) {

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, the database connection is still the same.

Comment: @carmel no, the query didn't find anything.

Comment: So thats your problem :)  mysql_fetch_object($result_id_check) returns FALSE and it is not an object.  and that's why when you call $row_check->ses_userid you get the error

Answer (score 1):

This error normally means that the query failed.

You should be checking for errors as you go like this, also the string concatenation can be made simpler if you use either the `{$_COOKIE['fe_typo_user']}` form of variable expansion inside a double quoted string, or alternatively this will also work `$_COOKIE[fe_typo_user]`

```
$sql = "select ses_userid 
        from fe_sessions 
        where ses_id = '{$_COOKIE['fe_typo_user']}'"

$result_id_check = mysql_query($sql);

if ( $result_id_check === false ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    echo 'Bad SQL : ' . $sql;
    exit;
}

$row_check = mysql_fetch_object($result_id_check);
```

This way when you make small mistakes with your SQL, you get told about them directly and you dont have to wonder what nay have gone wrong.

> Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
>   is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
>
> You should also be using parameterized queries ( available in the `mysqli_` and `PDO` database extensions, but not the old deprecated `mysql_` extension) to avoid [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Specially if you are using data got from `$_POST` or `$_GET` or `$_COOKIE`
>
> If you are considering moving to `mysqli_` or `PDO` you should read also read this [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it with `mysqli_query($connection, $query)` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `$row_check->ses_userid` just check whether $row_check is true or false.

```
if ($row_check) {
    if ($row_check->ses_userid) {

    }
}
```